# Network connection name

Tags: windows-10, router, dns, ethernet, network-adapter

[image]

The ethernet connection on my laptop shows as

```
Ethernet
SONOSWIFI
BroadcomNetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet Plus
```

About 4 months ago I setup a tiny LAN for a customer on a consumer grade router. It was to run their Sonos and so I called the router and SSID SONOSWIFI. Since then my ethernet connection has shown SONOSWIFI.

I've not been back and do not connect to that network ever, my ethernet connection still shows SONOSWIFI as the network name.

Right clicking and selecting rename gives me the option to overtype 'Ethernet' but not the SONOSWIFI. I cannot see an option under the adapter properties to change this.

Currently I'm on my office network, everything runs through pfSense that does everything; router, DHCP, DNS.

Other devices on this network simply show Network *X* where X is a number. I assume the router or DNS server should be broadcasting this information but I don't know what or where to configure that.

**EDIT.** The clients SONOSWIFI network was configured with a subnet like 192.168.1.0/24
The Network I am currently sat on has a subnet like 192.168.50.0/24. I have noted that this persists on a network with an IP subnet like 10.10.10.0

2 questions arise.

- How does Windows 10 establish what to populate that field with
- How do I override it or force it to recognise my current network (what ever that may be at the time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/28375-change-network-profile-name-windows-10-a.html) and [here](https://windowsreport.com/rename-network-windows-10/), network profiles may be edited or deleted through the registry editor. The basic steps are:

1. Open regedit with admin permissions.
2. Navigate to:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles
   ```
3. Each GUID subkey will have a `ProfileName` value. Find the GUID with your value of interest (e.g., SONOSWIFI) and change the `ProfileName` as desired or delete the key entirely.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. The first link highlights the interface under Network Profile in Local Security Policy which is probably the 'proper' way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

This name is based on the network environment you are connecting to.

For example: If you add your computer to a domain, the name will change to the domain's network environment, which may be a domain name or another name. If you quit the domain and then connect to your own ISP, the name will change again.

I am not sure if changing the registry is a permanent effect. Maybe you can try to reboot your network adapter or change the network environment you are connecting to.